# What is the reason behind band gap narrowing in semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I want to know why some semiconductors band gap decreases after doping with elements. ***Burstein-Moss band-filling effect*** can be useful to explain band gap widing in a semiconductor materials but i was unable to find any logical explanation for band narrowing effect. Can you please explain the mechanism of band gap narrowing.

This below quotes were taken from a research article.

> There is general agreement that two competing phenomena are dominant
>   in affecting the absorption edge in heavily doped semiconductors.
>   First, the well-known Burstein-Moss band-filling effect which shifts
>   positively the measured band-edge energy with increasing carrier
>   concentration. In this case the measured optical gap $E_{m}$ is the sum of
>   the optical gap of the lightly doped material $E_{0}$, plus that due to
>   filling of the conduction band due to Is $\Delta E_{BM}$, I. E. $E_{m}=E_{0}+E_{BM}$.
>   Thc second phenomenon which affects the optical absorption edge with
>   increasing donor density is due to a change in the nature and strength
>   of the interaction potentials between donors and the host crystal.
>   This latter effect gives rise to a band-gap shrinkage and to some
>   increased tailing of the absorption edge. In this case the measured
>   optical gap is $E_{m}=E_{0}+E_{BM}-\Delta E_{g}$., where $\Delta E_{g}$ is the gap shrinkage.

I didnt understand the explanation given in second phenomenon. What is author meant by due ***to a change in the nature and strength of the interaction potentials between donors and the host crystal***.

Advance thanks for your help

Comment: Hmmm... band gap narrowing seems quite complicated, here is something that makes sense, http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/palankovski/node39.html

Answer (score -1):

I found a paper titled: "A New and Simple Model for Plasma- and Doping-Induced Band Gap Narrowing" (by Ahmed Shaker and Abelhalim Zekry in the Journal of Electron Devices, Vol. 8, 2010, pp. 293-299) which has a more intuitive explanantion of why the band gap narrows.

link to the paper for the lazy: *A new and simple Model for Plasma and Doping and Doping induced Band Gap Narrowing* [[pdf]](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Abdelhalim_Zekry/publication/232711847_Ahmed_Shaker_and_Abdelhalim_Zekry_A_new_and_simple_Model_for_Plasma_and_Doping_and_Doping_induced_Band_Gap_Narrowing_Journal_of_Electronic_Dsvices_Vol._8_2010/links/004635261827304313000000.pdf)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain the important bits of the paper? Link-only answers are frowned upon because link rot can be an issue.